# git: rebase-like option for squashed + merged branches that have new commits?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a few commits `M1, M2` on a `main` branch, and then implement something on a `feature` branch. The implementation is good, and I `git merge --squash feature` into `main`, giving a new commit `M3`. My history looks like this:

```
main:      M1 -- M2 ---------- M3
                  \            /
feature:          F1 -- F2 -- F3
```

Now I mistakenly continue working off `feature`, adding a commits `F4` and `F5`. I would like to merge `F4` and `F5` into `main`, but I can't do so easily because `merge --squash` made the branch histories incompatible. (At least this is my understanding of the issue.)

**My resolution** has been a bit of surgery via

```sh
git checkout main
git checkout -b feature_new
git cherry-pick F4
git cherry-pick F5
git checkout main
git merge --squash feature_new
```

(replacing `F4` and `F5` with their SHAs, of course).

**My question**: is there some better way of using `git` to identify when commits have been squashed, and "rebasing" `feature` in a way that replaces `F1` through `F3` with `M3`? i.e. graphically:

*before this "rebase"*

```
main:      M1 -- M2 ---------- M3
                  \            /
feature:          F1 -- F2 -- F3 -- F4 -- F5
```

*after this "rebase"*

```
main:      M1 -- M2 ---------- M3
                                \
feature:                         F4 -- F5
```

Comment: The functionality that Git has for this is broken by squash merges.  If you used regular merges or rebases, this would be easy to do, but with squash merges, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to merge changes from feature branch to your main branch simply do:

```
git checkout main
```

then:

```
git merge feature --no-ff
```

you can do the same after you have already produced **m3** commit.